# Consume a WCF service from a console app as part of a SQL job?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, soa, console-application

I'm working with one WCF service which will be consuming records I queue up for it with another.  Service A will package up an object containing a series of records (I guess an XML document, haven't nailed down the format yet) queried from a database, and submit it to Service B for processing.

Service B is on a separate department's system and is out of my control, so I'm using my service to package the data to conform to B's inputs.

I'm thinking of instantiating my service via a client in a console app, which would be called as part of a SQL job on MS SQL 2005.

Could someone please suggest alternatives and any better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider packaging your service A code into [SQLCLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_CLR) and call it like another stored proc.